# Connection refused sqlalchemy Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm running flask app on Ubuntu 18.0 , flask_sqlalchemy and MYSQL database, when I try to log in sometimes I got 500 internal server error, I have to restart MYSQL server and Apache.

I check serevr log and I found this error , I couldn't understand it 
 error.log

```
ERROR:flask.app:Exception on / [POST], referer: {domain.com}
 Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: {domain.com}
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 583, in connect, referer: {domain.com}
     **kwargs), referer: {domain.com}
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection, referer: {domain.com}
     raise err, referer: {domain.com}
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection, referer: {domain.com}
     sock.connect(sa), referer: {domain.com}
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused, referer: {domain.com}
, referer: {domain.com}
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:, referer: {domain.com}
, referer: {domain.com}
Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: {domain.com}
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2158, in _wrap_pool_connect, referer: {domain.com}
   return fn(), referer: {domain.com}
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1805, in full_dispatch_request, referer: {domain.com}
  rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: {domain.com}
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1791, in dispatch_request, referer: {domain.com}
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args), referer: {domain.com}
File "/var/www/Dashboard/dashboard/routes.py", line 23, in login, referer: {domain.com}
  User = db.session.query(Users).filter_by(Email = request.form['Email']).first(), referer: {domain.com}
```

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SECRET_KEY'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost/database"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

from dashboard import routes
from dashboard import api
```

Comment: Please show us the code where you initialize the database.

Comment: @MartinKondor I updated it , thanks

Comment: Are you sure the database exists?

Comment: @MartinKondor yeah it's working for while , but when I come back after couple hours I get this error I restart mysql sever and apache it work again

Comment: @MartinKondor I'm still getting this error
 `ERROR:flask.app:Exception on /order [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 583, in connect
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection  sock.connect(sa)     ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Answer (score 1):

I was running out of memory that leads to MySQL server to crash every time I do POST or GET request.

I was using Ubuntu DigitalOcean droplet 25GB storage with 1GB RAM, with APACHE server and MYSQL server.

What I did is run MySQL server in standalone droplet and connect the flask app remotely and it's working very stable.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Connect to your database with a socket like this:

```
socket_location = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = \
    "mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost/database?unix_socket=" + socket_location
```

To find the correct location of your socket, try to search it in your database configuration file, like in **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**.

Before using the database make sure that it exists:

```py
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

# ...
app.run(...)
```